# how to populate and remove options in html select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four dropdowns and four options, all four dropdowns have same options. I am trying to remove options in other three dropdowns if user selects one option from current dropdown. If user changes again with a new value, new value option should remove and old value should populate again in other dropdowns. I did something but it is not working as expected.

Refer to the following jsFiddle(Updated): http://jsfiddle.net/ruq1jb0c/5/

```js
$('.inputcontrol').change(function() {
  var fields = ['Employee', 'Status', 'State', 'Supervisor'];
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.inputcontrol').not(this).find('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == value) {
      $(this).remove()
    }
  });

  $('.inputcontrol').each(function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      if (fields[i] != value) {
        if ($(this).find("option[value=" + fields[i] + "]").length == 0) {
          $(this).append("<option value=" + fields[i] + ">" + fields[i] + "</option>");

        }
      }

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field1" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field2" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field3" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field4" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: did u try anything ? give us some code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ruq1jb0c/4/

Comment: yes, please see in above link @sayalok

Comment: its not clear to us, what you want to do? can yu explain more??

Comment: You should include your code/jsfiddle in your question not in the comment section.

Comment: stackoverdlow is not allowing me to enter jsfiddle link

Comment: if i understand ur que properly
 all the dropdown option u set are static but u want them to change on the basis of top dropdown value.
so what u can do u can put ur dropdown options inside condition like
if this === true ? this.option : other.option
this is easy way but poor coding
or 
u can do it more dynamic way inside func

Comment: What @ sayalok is right and also instead of removing them why dont you try `.hide()` and `show()` on them instead.

Comment: It has to be remove due to some reasons

Comment: Ok but i cant understand your logic. you want that if some select Employee then Employee should be removed from the other dropdownlist etc. im i understanding this right ?

Comment: yes, and if user selected other option other than employee then again 'Employee' should populate in other dropdowns

Comment: Wouldn't you like to have the selects dynamically created by JS altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is an exmaple that will make this much simpler.
Read the comment to understand how it work

```js
var selectedFields = ['Employee', '', '', ''] // here is all selected Value for each dropdownList is saved
var drps = $(".inputcontrol");
function validate(){
drps.each(function(index, item){
      $(this).attr("index", index); // This is important where $(this).index() are not working 
     $(this).find("option").show(); // reset all option to visible
     var v = $(this).val();
     $.each(selectedFields, function(subIndex, subItem){
        if (index > subIndex) // here we hide all previews selected values 
            $(item).find("option[value='"+subItem+"']").hide();
     });
  });
}

drps.change(function(){
  var itemIndex = eval($(this).attr("index")); 
  selectedFields[itemIndex] = $(this).val()
  drps.each(function(index, item){ // reset all values of dropdown that are after the current dropdown
    if (index > itemIndex) {
        $(this).val("none")
        selectedFields[index] ="";
     }
  });
  validate();
});

validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="field1" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field2" class="inputcontrol">
  <option selected="selected" value="none">none</option>
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field3" class="inputcontrol">
  <option selected="selected" value="none">none</option>
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field4" class="inputcontrol">
 <option selected="selected" value="none">none</option>
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: great! it works. options will populated again, but user wont able to select duplicate value. Thanks much, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This made a difference: (as in your jsfiddle link)

```
if($(this).val()===value)
        $(this).hide()
 else  $(this).show() // this will unhide previously hidden options
```

and not '=='

see it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/site2goal/se7td85L/3/)

Comment: no its not working as expected, if you see selected value still populated in other dropdown

Comment: @Sanjay The current selected value is hidden from others. And recover after change in selection. This is what I think you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class and `addClass` & `removeClass`

On change find the option which have class `hide` and add or remove it

```js
$('.inputcontrol').change(function(e) {
  $('.inputcontrol').find('option.hide').removeClass('hide');
  $('.inputcontrol').not(this).find('option[value="' + e.target.value + '"]').addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field1" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field2" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field3" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<select id="field4" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: no its not working properly, still i am able to see same selected option in other dropdowns

Comment: because you have made default `Employee` selected. Remove that and add another option when nothing is selected

Comment: I am have added empty value, still able to see selected option in other dropdowns, please help me in other way

Answer (score 0):

Check code comments

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  
  // get id to exclude from hiding
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  
  // get value select for option hiding reference
  var val = $(this).val();
  
  // unhide all options
  $('select option').css('display', 'block');
  
  // loop through all select except the changed one
  // and hide all options with value from changed select
  $('select:not(#' + id + ')').each(function() {
    $(this).find('option[value="' + val + '"]').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field1" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field2" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field3" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="field4" class="inputcontrol">
  <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
  <option value="Status">Status</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
  <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option>
</select>
```