# How to fix that dependant jQuery dropdown select code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna make 3 dependant dropdowns where the options on select 2 will be depending on the selection on select 1 and the options on select 3 will depend on selection on depend 2,  Some of the select 2 options should have select 3 values and some should not have select 3 options if selected as shown on select2 labels.

I think the current code is working fine for the first and second dropdown but dont know how to link it with the third dropdown and make the third dropdown depend on the second one.

I found other codes doing that using JSON but since im totally new to js and jQuery that why i preferred to use a simple code like this.

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1" option-id="1">Group A</option>
    <option value="2" option-id="2">Group B</option>
    <option value="3" option-id="3">Group C</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="a" option-id="1">Product 1 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="b" option-id="1">Product 2 Standard and large</option>
    <option value="c" option-id="1">Product 3 Small and Standard</option>
    <option value="d" option-id="1">Product 4 Standard and Large</option>
    <option value="e" option-id="1">Product 5 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="f" option-id="1">Product 6 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="g" option-id="2">Product 7 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="h" option-id="2">Product 8 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="i" option-id="2">Product 9 No Sizes<option>
    <option value="i" option-id="3">Product 10 No Sizes<option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="aa" option-id="1">Small</option>
    <option value="bb" option-id="2">Standard</option>
    <option value="cc" option-id="3">Large</option>
</select>
```

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
        $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
    $select3 = $( '#select3' ), // I added that line but not sure if its correct

    $options_a = $select2.find( 'option' );
        $options_b = $select3.find( 'option' ); // I added that line but not sure if its correct

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
    $select2.html( $options_a.filter( '[option-id="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

// I added the next lines for select3 but not sure if they are correct
$select1.on( 'change', function() {
    $select3.html( $options_b.filter( '[option-id="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6faq5xwn/1/

Comment: i have just helped another guy with the same problem. have a look at the answer i made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303491/how-to-populate-and-remove-options-in-html-select/54304677?noredirect=1#comment95429854_54304677 and make sure to look at how i handle this problem by validating the index of the dropdownlist. If you still cant do it, will then help you resolv this problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code

HTML

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1" option-id="1">Group A</option>
    <option value="2" option-id="2">Group B</option>
    <option value="3" option-id="3">Group C</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="a" option-id="1">Product 1 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="b" option-id="1">Product 2 Standard and large</option>
    <option value="c" option-id="1">Product 3 Small and Standard</option>
    <option value="d" option-id="1">Product 4 Standard and Large</option>
    <option value="e" option-id="1">Product 5 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="f" option-id="1">Product 6 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="g" option-id="2">Product 7 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="h" option-id="2">Product 8 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="i" option-id="2">Product 9 No Sizes<option>
    <option value="i" option-id="3">Product 10 No Sizes<option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="aa" idx="a">Small</option>
    <option value="bb" idx="b">Standard</option>
    <option value="cc" idx="c">Large</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
        $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
    $select3 = $( '#select3' ), // I added that line but not sure if its correct

    $options_a = $select2.find( 'option' ),
        $options_b = $select3.find( 'option' ); // I added that line but not sure if its correct

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
    $select2.html( $options_a.filter( '[option-id="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

// I added the next lines for select3 but not sure if they are correct
$select2.on( 'change', function() {
    $select3.html( $options_b.filter( '[idx="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

Your select2 function was looking to filter by idx but the attribute in the html was still option-id

Moreover, your idx is looking to match the VALUE of select2 and therefore the values of the idx should be the corresponding letters.

Also a syntax error setting option_b variable

Comment: Thanks for reply, Unfortunately i need to store a specif data on value attripute for each option and summit it with POST that's why i used here a custom attribute instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/arabtornado/Lbx87ck6/1/

Unfortunately couldn't make the third dropdown work with custom attribute, It looks like it still filtering by value instead since it stopped working at all when i changed the names of values

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You can try this. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYWOJK?editors=1111

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$sel2Options = $('#select2').html();
$sel3Options = $('#select3').html();

$("#select3 option[option-id!='']").hide();

$('#select1').change(function(s){
  $sel1 = $(this).find(":selected").attr("option-id");

  $('#select2').html($sel2Options);  

  $("#select2 option[option-id!="+ $sel1 +"]").each(function(i,e) {
      if(e.value!="")
          $(this).hide();
  });

})

$('#select2').change(function(s){
  $sel2 = $(this).find(":selected").attr("option-id");

  $('#select3').html($sel3Options);  

  $("#select3 option[option-id!="+ $sel2 +"]").hide();

})
```

})

Comment: Unfortunately the filtering of the third dropdown is wrong, i named the select labels to reflect the intended filtering i need

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should do it for you. Your value assignments are preserved. 
The `sizes` attribute of the options in Select2 contains a comma-separated list of integers, and the `size` attribute of the options in Select3 contains a single integer.

The following code puts the option elements from Select3 into an array and iterates through them. For each one, it first hides the option, then checks whether its size is one of the sizes permitted for the currently selected option from Select2, and restores the display of any option with a permitted size. (If there are any valid sizes for the user to select, "Select your option" is also treated as a valid size so that it will be available to appear as the placeholder option.)

```
$select3.children().get().forEach(function(opt){
  opt.style.display= "none";
  if($select2[0][$select2[0].selectedIndex].dataset["sizes"].includes(opt.dataset["size"])){ 
    opt.style.display="";
  }
});
```

Here it is with the rest of the code, including the new data attributes in the HTML:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1" option-id="1">Group A</option>
    <option value="2" option-id="2">Group B</option>
    <option value="3" option-id="3">Group C</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="a" option-id="1" data-sizes="0">Product 1 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="b" option-id="1" data-sizes="2,3,9">Product 2 Standard and large</option>
    <option value="c" option-id="1" data-sizes="1,2,9">Product 3 Small and Standard</option>
    <option value="d" option-id="1" data-sizes="2,3,9">Product 4 Standard and Large</option>
    <option value="e" option-id="1" data-sizes="0">Product 5 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="f" option-id="1" data-sizes="0">Product 6 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="g" option-id="2" data-sizes="0">Product 7 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="h" option-id="2" data-sizes="0">Product 8 No Sizes</option>
    <option value="i" option-id="2" data-sizes="0">Product 9 No Sizes<option>
    <option value="j" option-id="3" data-sizes="0">Product 10 No Sizes<option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="" disabled data-size="9" selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="aa" data-size="1">Small</option>
    <option value="bb" data-size="2">Standard</option>
    <option value="cc" data-size="3">Large</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
    $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
    $select3 = $( '#select3' ), // I added that line but not sure if its correct
    $options_a = $select2.find( 'option' );

  $select1.on( 'change', function() {
    $select2.html( $options_a.filter( '[option-id="' + this.value + '"]' ));
  }).trigger( 'change' );

// For $select3
  $select2.on( 'change', function() {
    $select3.children().get().forEach(function(opt){
      opt.style.display= "none";
      if($select2[0][$select2[0].selectedIndex].dataset["sizes"].includes(opt.dataset["size"])){ 
        opt.style.display="";
      }
    });
  } ).trigger( 'change' );

</script>
```